# Why is physical process in Castalia outputting wrong data?

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to simulate a sensor array in Castalia capable of using more than one sensor per node but when I run the simulation it takes the names of the sensors as one item and ends up displaying the sensor index and value of the sensor mentioned first. Please help!! how can I get it to detect more than one sensor per node
omnetpp.ini (valueReporting)

```
[General]

# ==========================================================
# Always include the main Castalia.ini file
# ==========================================================

include ../Parameters/Castalia.ini

sim-time-limit = 600s

SN.field_x = 100                    # meters
SN.field_y = 100                    # meters

SN.numNodes = 36
SN.deployment = "6x6"

SN.node[*].Communication.Radio.RadioParametersFile = "../Parameters/Radio/CC2420.txt"

SN.node[*].Communication.MACProtocolName = "TMAC"

SN.node[*].Communication.RoutingProtocolName = "MultipathRingsRouting"
#SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.collectTraceInfo = true

SN.node[*].ApplicationName = "ValueReporting"
SN.node[3].Application.isSink = true

# test 2 physical processes
SN.numPhysicalProcesses = 2  
SN.physicalProcess[0].printDebugInfo = true 
SN.physicalProcess[1].printDebugInfo = true 
SN.physicalProcess[0].description = "Degrees Celsius"  
SN.physicalProcess[1].description = "Blood Glucose"     
SN.physicalProcess[0].inputType = 1         
SN.physicalProcess[1].inputType = 1         
#SN.physicalProcess[0].directNodeValueAssignment = "(0) 0:25 1:23 2:21 3:24 4:26"
#SN.physicalProcess[1].directNodeValueAssignment = "(0) 0:360 1:380 2:375 3:390 4:390"
SN.node[*].SensorManager.​numSensingDevices = 2 
SN.node[*].SensorManager.​sensorTypes = "Temperature Bloodglucose" 
SN.node[*].SensorManager.​corrPhyProcess = "0 1"
```

In the SensorManager.ned file, I changed these lines as for the rest of the file everything is left as is

```
string sensorTypes = default ("Temperature,Bloodglucose");
    // string array of comma-separated Names for the sensing devices

string corrPhyProcess = default ("0,1");
```

Now the temperature physical process files
TemperaturePhysicalProcess.ned

```
package physicalProcess.temperaturePhysicalProcess;

simple TemperaturePhysicalProcess like physicalProcess.iPhysicalProcess {
 parameters:
    bool collectTraceInfo = default (true);

    double temperature = default (37); //normal body temperature is 37 degrees celcius


    string description = default ("Degrees Celsius");

 gates:
    output toNode[];
    input fromNode[];
}
```

TemperaturePhysicalProcess.h

```
#ifndef _TEMPERATUREPHYSICALPROCESS_H_
#define _TEMPERATUREPHYSICALPROCESS_H_

#define SIMTIME_STEP 0.01

#include "CastaliaModule.h"
#include "PhysicalProcessMessage_m.h"

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    simtime_t time;
    double x;
    double y;
} sourceSnapshot;

class TemperaturePhysicalProcess: public CastaliaModule {
 private:
    bool printDebugInfo;

    int temperature; 

    const char *description;
protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage * msg);
    virtual void finishSpecific();
};

#endif
```

TemperaturePhysicalProcess.cc

```
#include "TemperaturePhysicalProcess.h"

Define_Module(TemperaturePhysicalProcess);

void TemperaturePhysicalProcess::initialize()
{

    temperature=37;  
    //Search for snapshots in castalia manual
}

void TemperaturePhysicalProcess::handleMessage(cMessage * msg)
{
    if (msg->getKind() != PHYSICAL_PROCESS_SAMPLING)
    {
        opp_error("Physical Process received message other than PHYSICAL_PROCESS_SAMPLING");
    }

    PhysicalProcessMessage *receivedMsg = check_and_cast < PhysicalProcessMessage * >(msg);
    int nodeIndex = receivedMsg->getSrcID();

    // Send reply back to the node who made the request
    receivedMsg->setValue(temperature);
    send(receivedMsg, "toNode", nodeIndex);
}

void TemperaturePhysicalProcess::finishSpecific() {}
```

Now we'll go to the Blood Glucose physical process
BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess.ned

```
package physicalProcess.bloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess;

simple BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess like physicalProcess.iPhysicalProcess {
 parameters:
    bool collectTraceInfo = default (false);
    int averagebloodglucose = default (100); // the amount is in mg per dL
    int age = default (20);
    string description = default ("Blood Glucose");

 gates:
    output toNode[];
    input fromNode[];
}
```

BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess.h

```
#ifndef _BLOOODGLUCOSELEVELPHYSICALPROCESS_H_
#define _BLOOODGLUCOSELEVELPHYSICALPROCESS_H_

#define SIMTIME_STEP 0.01

#include "CastaliaModule.h"
#include "PhysicalProcessMessage_m.h"

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    simtime_t time;
    double x;
    double y;
} sourceSnapshot;

class BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess: public CastaliaModule {
 private:
    bool printDebugInfo;
    int averagebloodglucose;
    double A1c;
    const char *description;
protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage * msg);
    virtual void finishSpecific();
};

#endif
```

BloodGlucoseLevelLevelPhysicalProcess.cc

```
#include "BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess.h"

Define_Module(BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess);

void BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess::initialize()
{
    averagebloodglucose = par("averagebloodglucose");
    description = par("description").stringValue();
    A1c = (46.7 + averagebloodglucose) / 28.7;
    //Search for snapshots in castalia manual

}

void BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess::handleMessage(cMessage * msg)
{
    if (msg->getKind() != PHYSICAL_PROCESS_SAMPLING)
        opp_error("Physical Process received message other than PHYSICAL_PROCESS_SAMPLING");

    PhysicalProcessMessage *receivedMsg = check_and_cast < PhysicalProcessMessage * >(msg);
    int nodeIndex = receivedMsg->getSrcID();
    //int sensorIndex = receivedMsg->getSensorIndex();
    double returnValue;

    // Send reply back to the node who made the request
    //receivedMsg->setValue(returnValue);
    receivedMsg->setValue(A1c);
    send(receivedMsg, "toNode", nodeIndex);

}

void BloodGlucoseLevelPhysicalProcess::finishSpecific() {

}
```

Since I'm running the simulation using the ValueReporting application
ValueReporting.h

```
#define _VALUEREPORTING_H_

#include "VirtualApplication.h"
#include "ValueReportingPacket_m.h"

using namespace std;

enum ValueReportingTimers {
    REQUEST_SAMPLE = 1,
    SEND_DATA = 2,

};

class ValueReporting: public VirtualApplication {
 private:
    double maxSampleInterval;
    double minSampleInterval;

    int routingLevel;
    double lastSensedValue;
    int currSentSampleSN;

    double randomBackoffIntervalFraction;
    bool sentOnce;

    int recipientId;
    string recipientAddress;

 protected:
    void startup();
    void fromNetworkLayer(ApplicationPacket *, const char *, double, double);
    void handleSensorReading(SensorReadingMessage *);
    void timerFiredCallback(int);
    void requestSensorReading(const char *);


};

#endif              // _VALUEREPORTING_APPLICATIONMODULE_H_
```

ValueReporting.cc

```
#include "ValueReporting.h"
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>     // std::string, std::to_string
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atof */
#include <math.h>
#include<sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

Define_Module(ValueReporting);

void ValueReporting::startup()
{
    maxSampleInterval = ((double)par("maxSampleInterval")) / 1000.0;
    minSampleInterval = ((double)par("minSampleInterval")) / 1000.0;
    currSentSampleSN = 0;
    randomBackoffIntervalFraction = genk_dblrand(0);
    sentOnce = false;
    setTimer(REQUEST_SAMPLE, maxSampleInterval * randomBackoffIntervalFraction);
}

void ValueReporting::timerFiredCallback(int index)
{
    switch (index) {

        case REQUEST_SAMPLE:{
            requestSensorReading("Temperature");
            //requestSensorReading("Urine");

            setTimer(REQUEST_SAMPLE, maxSampleInterval);

            break; 
        }      
    }
}

void ValueReporting::fromNetworkLayer(ApplicationPacket * genericPacket,
         const char *source, double rssi, double lqi)
{
    ValueReportingDataPacket *rcvPacket = check_and_cast<ValueReportingDataPacket*>(genericPacket);
    ValueReportData theData = rcvPacket->getExtraData();

        trace() << "Sink received from: " << theData.nodeID << " \tvalue=" << rcvPacket->getData();

}
void ValueReporting::handleSensorReading(SensorReadingMessage * rcvReading)
{
    int sensIndex =  rcvReading->getSensorIndex();

     string sensType(rcvReading->getSensorType());

    double sensValue = rcvReading->getSensedValue();

    double x_coor = mobilityModule->getLocation().x; 
    double y_coor = mobilityModule->getLocation().y;
string sensorindex = to_string(sensIndex);
    string sensvalue = to_string(sensValue);
    string xcoor = to_string(x_coor);
    string ycoor = to_string(y_coor);


    string sensorinfo= sensorindex + " " + sensvalue + " " + xcoor + " " + ycoor + " " + sensType;
    trace() << sensorinfo; 
ValueReportData tmpData;
    tmpData.nodeID = (unsigned short)self;
    tmpData.locX = mobilityModule->getLocation().x;
    tmpData.locY = mobilityModule->getLocation().y;

    ValueReportingDataPacket *packet2Net =
        new ValueReportingDataPacket("Value reporting pck", APPLICATION_PACKET);
    packet2Net->setExtraData(tmpData);
    packet2Net->setData(sensValue);
    packet2Net->setSequenceNumber(currSentSampleSN);
    currSentSampleSN++;

    toNetworkLayer(packet2Net, SINK_NETWORK_ADDRESS);
    //toNetworkLayer(packet2Net, "6");
    sentOnce = true;
}
void ValueReporting::requestSensorReading(const char * type){
    SensorReadingMessage *reqMsg =
        new SensorReadingMessage("App to Sensor Mgr: sample request", SENSOR_READING_MESSAGE);

    if(type == "Temperature"){
    reqMsg->setSensorType(type);
    reqMsg->setSensorIndex(0);
    }
if(type =="BloodGlucose"){
    reqMsg->setSensorType(type);
    reqMsg->setSensorIndex(1);
    }
    send(reqMsg, "toSensorDeviceManager");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some things I noticed:

There is no `printDebugInfo` parameter in the PhysicalProcess module. Probably what you are after is `collectTraceInfo`.

If you just want to update the values some parameters take, it's not a good idea to edit ned files. This is what ini files are for. So instead of changing the default values in ned files, simply assign these values in your ini file. For example, you already assign these parameters in your ini file:

```
SN.node[*].SensorManager.​sensorTypes = "Temperature Bloodglucose" 
SN.node[*].SensorManager.​corrPhyProcess = "0 1"
```

You do not need to set them in the ned file as well. Also notice that in the ned file you set the second string as "0,1" not "0 1". The ini file will override the value of the ned file, so what you'll get it "0 1". Fortunately, space separated values is the correct syntax.

You then start defining new .ned .cc and .h files. Why? These do not have any effect. You have not set the variable `SN.physicalProcessName` in your ini file. This means it takes the default value which is `CustomizablePhysicalProcess`. You seem to be treating your physical process modules as `CustomizablePhysicalProcess` because I see you define their parameters `inputType` and `directNodeValueAssignment`, which only exist for the `CustomizablePhysicalProcess` module. So I do not understand what you expect to get by trying to define new physical process modules altogether.

Since you have 2 physical processes, it means that the SensorManager in every node needs to connect to these 2 physical process (the 2 modules that define your physical processes). To do this just set all the parameters of your SensorManager that can be defined as an array (formatted as a space-separated string) as arrays of 2 items.

You can find all relevant parameters in the SensorManager.ned (but do NOT edit the ned file, just set them in your ini file). Here are the parameters just for reference (note that **you have already set `sensorTypes` and `corrPhyProcess`** in your ini file, you just need to **also set the rest**) :

```
string pwrConsumptionPerDevice = default ("0.02");
string sensorTypes = default ("Temperature");   // Humidity OR Temperature OR Light
string corrPhyProcess = default ("0");      //holds the indexes of the corresponding phy processes for
                                            //each sensor (usually it should be : "0 1 2 3")
string maxSampleRates = default ("1");      //number of samples per second for each sensor
string devicesBias = default ("0.1");       //If the output signal is not zero when the measured property is zero
string devicesDrift = default ("");         //If the output signal slowly changes independent of the 
                                            //measured property                     
string devicesNoise = default ("0.1");      //random deviation of the signal that varies in time
string devicesHysterisis = default ("");    //the sensor not instantly follows the change of the property 
                                            //being measured and therefore involves the history of the 
                                            //measured property
string devicesSensitivity = default ("0");  //holds the minimum value which can be sensed by each sensing device.
string devicesResolution = default ("0.001");   //holds the sensing resolution for each device
```

I am not sure whether there are other problems with multiple phyProcesses and multiple sensing modalities, because this feature has not been tested in versions after 2.0, so it might not work at all (but hopefully it's a small adjustment to make it work).